# Best way to return the max shape of a file in a directory?

Tags: python, tensor

I have a large directory of 3D images (.nii). I'm working to loop through them all and return the maximum shape of the largest file (x, y, z).

```
r = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".nii"):
            r.append(file)
print(r)

shapes = np.array([s.spatial_shape for s in r])
print(shapes.max(axis=0))
```

Produces a list of the images I want, but when I try to get their dimensions they're read as a list of strings, which have no spatial_shape. I'm brand new to python, so excuse any ignorance, but I think I need r to be a list of tensors, not strings. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So currently you are appending the **path to the images not the images themselves**, to solve this you need to load each of the images.

Since it's not clear how many images you are dealing with, a quick word of advice - dont save all the images and then loop through them but load each one and save their dimensions.

After you are done retrieving the maximal size should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm assuming that you can't use something like `PIL` (Pillow) to read these files... Which led me to the [`nibabel`](https://nipy.org/nibabel/) library, after determining that `.nii` seems to be a format for neuroimage data.

I don't have any local `.nii` files to test this on, but I believe the following should work.

```py
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib  # <-- the library I mentioned

neuro_images = Path(data_dir).rglob("*.nii")

# Wrapping `p` in `str` as I'm not sure that `nib.load` can handle Path objects
image_shapes = [nib.load(str(p)).shape for p in neuro_images]
image_shapes = np.asarray(image_shapes)

# This means of determining the `max` greedily finds maximums, so a 
# case where you have `(1, 2, 10)` and `(3, 2, 2)` will report the 
# latter as `max`, even though `(1, 2, 10)` has the largest shape.
print(image_shapes.max(axis=0))

# In an effort to resolve the above comment, you might also consider:
  # Condenses the rows into a single product for "size"
shape_prods = np.apply_along_axis(np.prod, -1, image_shapes)
shape_argmax = np.argmax(shape_prods)
print(image_shapes[shape_argmax])
```

For more on what [`rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) is doing, take a look at the docs.

---

**Explanation:** I first start by "globbing" (matching based on particular criteria, i.e. `*.nii`) much in the way you can with `ls` in a Unix command line. This returns a `List[Path]`, which I then iterate over to let `nibabel` load and retrieve the `shape` property it contains, [per their docs](https://nipy.org/nibabel/gettingstarted.html). Then I through the `List[Tuple]` over to `np` to create the matrix you're expecting.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately didn't work but I do think it's a step closer than my answer!